# Limit user to their profile page

Tags: php, mysql

On my website I have a user login system, when they login they are taken to their profile page, which is deism ate by their uid. The thing is, there was nothing to stop a user just changing the uid and going to someone else's profile and Acting as them. To stop this I implemented a URL/MySQL system by which if the uid of the user is not the uid in the URL, they are redirected to their own profile. The problem here is that on the profile there are forms which change the URL, in doing so removing the uid query, resulting in the page (because the uid is missing) taking you to your profile and ignoring the form input.

The code is:

```
<?php
mysql_connect ('x', 'x', 'x');
mysql_select_db ('x');

if(isset($_COOKIE['wd_un'])) {
    $un = $_COOKIE['wd_un'];
    $pass = $_COOKIE['wd_pass'];

    $cook = "SELECT * FROM x WHERE username = '$un' AND password = '$pass' limit 1";
    $cookr = mysql_query($cook) or die (mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($cookr) == 0) {
            header ("Location: index.php");
        }
        else {
            $urluid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['uid']);
            $uidcheck = "SELECT * FROM x WHERE username = '$un' AND password = '$pass'";
            $uidcheckq = mysql_query($uidcheck) or die (mysql_error());
            while($rcu = mysql_fetch_assoc($uidcheckq)) {
                $dbuid = $rcu['uid'];
                        if($urluid != $dbuid) {
                            header ("location: home.php?uid=$dbuid");
                        }
                        else {
                        }
            }
        }
    }
mysql_close();
?>
```

Is there a work around?

Comment: If you know who they are through the session, why even have the URL parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code block you have here is riddled with badness.

First, you should absolutely never store a user's password in a cookie.
You SHOULD store only a session ID in the cookie, then store the rest of the session data in a session table in your DB that contains the user's id and any other things that you may want to have basic access to... password should not be in this table either.

Now, you can use the user_id in the URL safely cause the cross reference will keep people out.

on load of course you cross reference the mysql result from your session table that was pulled based on your cookie id. Obviously boot them if they don't match.

As for your form redirecting, you need to restructure how you handle posting then. You can make your profile page always pull only the profile related to the session id in your cookie. That would remove the dependency on URL and solve this problem completely.

Also - Please look into mysql_real_escape_string() to sanitize your inputs. It is incredibly dangerous to blindly accept cookie info for a mysql query. Unless you really do aim to leave huge injection holes in your site.

Comment: So start session, set a cookie with the session id, store the users username, ppassword and uid into a table of sessions, lookup the session in the table by using the cookies, if the users username and password in the sessions table match those in the user_db table then load their own page by selecting the info from the database where the uid is equal to the uid in the sessions table?

Comment: Not quite. When they log in using their username and pw you create a unique id any number of ways. this is one: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php. Then you store only that id in a cookie. Then in your session table you store that id with ONLY the user id. no password. On page load you can either pull the profile related to the id in their cookie OR cross reference the user_id related to your cookie with the user_id in the URL if you are still using that method. You can refresh and reset this cookie id every page load if you are worried about security.

Comment: Also, don't confuse my use of the word session with php's session(). You don't actually need to set a $_SESSION var of any kind. Your comment is mostly correct except that you do not need to check the password. in this case the unique ID of the cookie kind of serves as that since a good unique ID that refreshes on page load will be almost impossible to guess. all you do is pull the profile based on the user_id found in relation to the cookie id. If the user happens to have a cookie set AND that id is found in your session table then you should be safe. you can include a timestamp too if needed

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the Cookie ID to identify the user rather than pulling the user if from the URL. If cookieID does not match UserID, then redirect to their own profile.

Basically, never use the url to pass user ids for private data. Always references the cookie.

Relying on only the URL string to identify a user is a HUGE security hole on top of the usability issue you've described.

Comment: Okay, I'll change it to cookie, but then how do I use the cookie to limit the person to only their profile?

Comment: basically.. userid == cookieID so every page they go to only shows their information. No redirect needed. Based on what yo0u've posted, there should never be a need to add a user id to the url string. Just read the cookie.